# How to specify a log when autostarting in linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, dropbox

How do I specify the log when autostarting a program in linux mint. For example I change the Dropbox startup script to:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dropbox
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
Exec="export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=''; dropbox start -i > /tmp/dropbox.log 2>&1"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=true
```

but `/tmp/dropbox.log` does not exist.